# Efficient acceleration structure for moving 3D objects in scene

Tags: collision-detection, 3d, bounding-boxes, culling

I am implementing a 3D FPS game in C++. The game has large outdoors areas with both static and dynamic objects in the scene, with the following implicit assumptions:

- *Static objects:*

  - Do not move after initialization
  - Only added to scene during load time, all in one go
  - Examples: buildings, plants, obstacles, etc.
- *Dynamic objects:*

  - Can be expected to move at any time
  - Can be added to or removed from the scene at any time
  - Examples: players, vehicles, moveable physics objects, etc.

I want to implement acceleration structures that can efficiently handle collision detection on the objects in the scene (e.g raycasts, frustum culling, etc.) *NOTE: I am only doing these tests on the bounding volume level, i.e no polygon-ray/box/etc. tests. The goal here is to have an efficient method for early-outs before testing on the polygon level. In other words, let's assume all the static/dynamic objects are simple 3D boxes of various sizes.*

For static objects, I found that I can just create a Bounding Volume Hierarchy using their AABBs, which I've already tested and found to be quite efficient. I want to do something similar with the dynamic objects, i.e use their bounding volumes to create and update an acceleration structure at runtime.

So far, the only candidates I found are Spatial Hashing and Dynamic Octrees, but I could not find a lot of material for this specific use case, nor is it clear which of the two is more efficient. Also, I am not sure how to efficiently update the scene whenever the objects change. I can think of two approaches, which are indicated in the following pseudocode:

```
struct RayResult;
struct RayCast;
class RenderObject;

class DynamicScene
{
public:
    void addObj(RenderObject* obj) { /* Add object, update structure... */ }
    void removeObj(RenderObject* obj) { /* Remove object, update structure... */ }  
    void updateObj(RenderObject* obj) 
    { 
        /* Update the acceleration structure based on the changes in the object */ 
        updateAccelerationStructure(obj);
    }
    
    void perFrameUpdate(float dt)
    {
        // Update all the objects in the scene
        for(RenderObject& obj : m_sceneObjects)
        {
            obj.update(dt);
        }
            
        /* OPTION 1: update the scene here, after all objects have been updated? */
        updateAccelerationStructure();
    }
    
    RayResult rayTest(const RayCast& ray)
    {
        RayResult result;
        
        // Test all the dynamic objects using the accelerator structure
        // Add objects where we hit the OBB to the result struct
        // ...
        
        return result;
    }
};

class RenderObject
{
public:
    // Assume it has a 3D matrix for position/orientation, and an OBB that is updated whenever the transform changes
    // ...
    void update(float dt)
    {
        // ...
        /* OPTION 2: update the scene here, based on the changes to this one object? */
        if(transformChanged())
        {
            m_scene->updateObj(this);
        }
    }   
private:
    DynamicScene* m_scene;
};
```

Option 1 would result in a single update to the entire acceleration structure, but would require constantly inspecting all the objects for changes. Option 2 would only update if an object actually changed, but it also means N objects changing in a frame will result in N updates to the acceleration structure.

Thus, my questions are:

1. For the above use-case, which 3D acceleration structure is optimal, or at least most frequently used in game dev?
2. What is the ideal per-frame update procedure for said acceleration structure?

Comment: Instead of checking on all transforms for change, its less consuming to create, per frame (or step), a linked list of changed objects (instead of setting a dirt flag)

Comment: @Icebone1000 True, but that isn't really the bottleneck in my app. Also, I have since decided to just use Spatial Hashing.